# wcf Authentication Token Implementation - How to do

Tags: .net, asp.net, wcf, web-services, wcf-authentication

I need to implement token authentication between the user of my wcf services and my server.

1- User will request a token with his username, nickname and password from server and server will respond with a token if the credentials are correct?

**Question For 1**

- Should I create token for every single request or can I make it some storage to use the same token for specific period of time. What is the best way of doing that? any example on the web for this implementation?
- After token creation, where should I store the token? inside a database table or inside the memory? or any other way?
- What should I return if the credentials are wrong?
- how can I prevent the user from sending so many token requests in a short period of time?

2- Then user will use that token to use my service.

**Question For 2**

- how the client can pass the token to server? along with the query string? what is the best approach of doing that?

Any example or suggestion would be great.

Answer (score -1):

you can pass the token in the request header.

take a look at Oauth

Comment: this is not much of an answer.